# Do i need a streaming server if i want make an video app?

Tags: android, video-streaming

I want to make an app where users can upload and watch videos.
Now my question is, do i need a streaming server for that?
Or is an dedicated server enough? Because the streaming servers are very expensive.
I have searched a lot for that but i dont find an good answer for that.
Thank you much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need a streaming server for that?

No.

> Is a dedicated server enough?

Maybe.

It depends how many users you expect to have. A standard all-purpose dedicated server should be able to do the job up to a certain point.

[Hardware requirement for video serving to 400 concurrent users](https://serverfault.com/questions/189697/hardware-requirement-for-video-serving-to-400-concurrent-users)